# SQL query transposing columns

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table in the following structure:

```
id | att1 | att2 | att3
-----------------------
1  |  a1  |  b1  |  c1
2  |  a2  |  b2  |  c2
3  |  a3  |  b3  |  c3
```

And I want to transpose the columns to become rows for each id. Like this:

```
id  |  attname  |  value
------------------------
1   |   att1    |   a1
1   |   att2    |   b1
1   |   att3    |   c1
2   |   att1    |   a2
2   |   att2    |   b2
2   |   att3    |   c2
3   |   att1    |   a3
3   |   att2    |   b3
3   |   att3    |   c3
```

I was reading up on the PIVOT function and wasn't sure if it would do the job or how to use it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: MySQL and Oracle are different products, with somewhat different versions of SQL. Which product are you using?

Comment: @jarlh Sorry about that, I'm using Oracle.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do `UNION ALL`:

```
select id, 'att1' as attname, att1 as value from tablename
union all
select id, 'att2' as attname, att2 as value from tablename
union all
select id, 'att3' as attname, att3 as value from tablename
```

Note that `VALUE` is a reserved word in SQL, so if that's your real column name you need to double quote it, `"value"`.

Comment: I won't use this solution as you query the same table 3 times. Not the fastest way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use unpivot for this task.

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
UNPIVOT (
value FOR att_name 
IN (att1 as 'att1', att2 as 'att2', att3 as 'att3')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method :

```
SELECT id,attname, value 
FROM Yourtable 
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES ('att1',att1), ('att2',att2), ('att3',att3)) t(attname, value)
```